# Vuetify v-date-picker doesn't work correctly

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have copied the example of Vuetify date picker from the official documentation:

```xml
<v-row justify="center">
  <v-date-picker v-model="picker"></v-date-picker>
</v-row>
```

This code gives me the following result:

[image: The date picker that I get]

The desired result:

[image: The desired result]

The DP shows up only when hovering on what looks like an input, The Vuetify version is 2.5.0

**This is the app structure:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
   <v-app id="my-app">
     <mit-side-bar @sideBarOpened="hover_handler"></mit-side-bar>
     <template>
       <div class="text-center">
         <v-overlay :value="hover" z-index="5"></v-overlay>
       </div>
     </template>
     <v-main style="background: #E5E5E5">
       <slot></slot>
     </v-main>
     <v-footer padless color="#FBFDFF">
       <v-col
         class="text-center"
         cols="12"
         style="color: #899BAF"
       >
         {{ new Date().getFullYear() }} —
         Система мониторинга социально-экономического развития АЗРФ
       </v-col>
     </v-footer>
   </v-app>
 </div></template>
```

Comment: What do you want specific, do you want to have the current date highlighted?

Comment: The picker you get uses the `no-title` property to hide the title panel. [Proof.](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/b738de5c279840a30eb640f73bf61a1c8ac2a7fd/packages/vuetify/src/mixins/picker/index.ts#L48)

Comment: my qustion is why am I getting a different result, even the code is the same as in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

As it is mentioned [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/#api) you must wrap it in a v-app component in order for your application to work properly.
Try like

```html
<v-app id="inspire">
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-date-picker v-model="picker"></v-date-picker>
  </v-row>
</v-app>
```

Comment: yes it is wrapped by v-app, but it doesn't work properly!

Comment: If it is possible, could you share with us the whole code?

Comment: Also, which browser do you use?

Comment: The project is too big, I can share some parts! the browser is Chrome.

Comment: Is v-date-picker in the mit-side-bar? If so, could you post it also?

Comment: no it is inside v-main which contains a slot, the code above is a layout!

Comment: Do you use [V-Calendar](https://vcalendar.io/datepicker.html) in the project? Because what you got is similar to v-date-picker of vcalendar.

Comment: I have installed it and solved the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer

```html
<v-app>
    YOUR ORIGIN CODE PASTE HERE
</v-app>
```

Long answer ->
Vuetify need to follow this structure.

```html
<v-app>
    <v-row>
        <v-CHOOSE-APP></v-CHOOSE-APP>
    </v-row>
</v-app>
```

Comment: It is following this structure!